# Put this logic into a Repository or a Service

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, service-layer

Should I put this method into my ISchoolclassCodeRepository or my ISchoolclassService?

```
/// <summary>
        /// The client passes newly created and existing schoolclass codes.
        /// The newly created schoolclass codes are returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newAndExistingSchoolclassCodes">All schoolclass codes and the newly created by the user</param>
        /// <param name="schoolyearId">The related schoolyear for a schoolclass code</param>
        /// <returns>The newly created schoolclass codes</returns>
        public IEnumerable<SchoolclassCode> GetNewCreatedSchoolclassCode(IEnumerable<SchoolclassCode> newAndExistingSchoolclassCodes, int schoolyearId)
        {
            var existingSchoolclassCodes = _uniOfWork.SchoolclassCodeRepository.GetSchoolclassCodes(schoolyearId).ToList();
            var newSchoolclassCodes = existingSchoolclassCodes.Except(newAndExistingSchoolclassCodes,new SchoolclassCodeComparer());
            return newSchoolclassCodes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be more like application logic, in your case this would be implemented in your service. However, this often goes into an application layer. [Here's some more information](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-1/) that explains the various layers, maybe you want to adopt some of these concepts.

Repositories only hold data access logic: this means CRUD-like operations.

Comment: Yes I put it into my service. The repository has the FetchById method called within the service where I do the linq except stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My vote will be for `ISchoolclassService`, if you have one. I would't create one just for this purpose however.

It also depends on what `SchoolclassCodeComparer` does. If it has it's own data access, then it would be invoking the same repository to fetch school codes?

If there is a way one could pass the constraint imposed by `SchoolclassCodeComparer` to the query, then I would have this in the repository. Postprocessing of resultset using various rules could reside in the service.

I prefer to have the repository layer deal with DataAccess. Logic in Dataaccess would be limited to constructing parameters, and creating projections of result returned (if required).

Massaging/filtering the dataset based on any other business logic could be the service's job.

Comment: There are no parameters to construct or result(set) ?! I use an ORM tool.

Comment: Not sure I understood right, but what I meant was say you have a list of `SchoolCode` to filter, you could pass it as a "Not In" filter to your database. This would mean converting the list to a comma separated string, this logic can lie in the repository itself. Using ORM you can save this hassle, and benefit from LINQ as well.